# inequality involving logarithms and summations

Tags: calculus, inequality

Is is true that $\sum \limits_{j=a}^{b} \frac{1}{j^2 \ln^2 j} \leq \frac{1}{(a-1)\ln (a-1)}-\frac{1}{b \ln b}$

for all choices of $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: Whats the background on this inequality? Any info that could help?

Comment: approximating $\sum \frac{1}{p^2}$ where $p$ is prime number running from $a$ to $b$ using the known approximation $p_j = j \ln j$ @siegehalver

Comment: There are some issues with $a=1$, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to consider a right-hand Riemann sum for the function $f(x) = 1/(x\ln(x))^2$ on the interval $(a-1, b)$ and note that, when $a-1>1$, it follows that 
$$
\frac{1}{(x\ln(x))^2} < \frac{1+\ln(x)}{(x\ln(x))^2}
$$
for $a-1<x<b$.  Integrating the function on the right-hand side of the above inequality yields the right-hand side of the inequality you wish to establish.  I'll leave the rest (including valid values for $a$) to you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: For integer $b\geqslant j\geqslant a> 2$, show

$$\frac1{(j \log j)^2} < \frac1{j \log j \cdot (j-1)\log (j-1)} < \frac1{(j-1)\log(j-1)} - \frac1{j \log j} $$

Now sum telescopically...